# I can't get my buttons to have rounded corners or change color on hover

Tags: css

I have a button that I am using in multiple places on our website. Kind of an intricate issue. In the header it shows up with rounded corners but will not change color on hover. In the main body of a page it will change color on hover but will not have rounder corners. Here is the code.

```
.donate-button {
 display: block;
 height: 45px;
 width: 120px;
 background: rgba(255, 204, 5, .9);
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) !important;
 text-align: center;
 font: regular 8px/45px "Montserrat", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
 -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
 border-radius: 3px;
}
a.donate-button {
 text-decoration: none;
}
a.donate-button:hover {
 background: rgba(255, 213, 6, .9) !important;
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) !important;
}
```

Comment: Maybe also supply some HTML?

Comment: @ketan, we said that at the same split second ;) well actually one second apart...

Comment: Post a complete example, including your HTML

Comment: Use your browser's dev tools to see what properties are being applied.

Comment: hey everybody, thanks for getting back to me. I'm actually not sure what the html is. I have been using a tool called Visual Composer. So it easily adds buttons in different ways. I was simply adding a css class and referencing it in my style.css. But if anyone knows what the html should be I could use that instead...?  thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super simple fix! Remove the "a" from the hover class!
http://jsfiddle.net/ycUB6/10706/

```
.donate-button {
 display: block;
 height: 45px;
 width: 120px;
 background: rgba(255, 204, 5, .9);
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) !important;
 text-align: center;
 font: regular 8px/45px "Montserrat", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
 -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
 border-radius: 3px;
}
a.donate-button {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.donate-button:hover {
 background: rgba(255, 213, 6, .9) !important;
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) !important;
}
```

**EDIT**

After some back and forth in the comments I managed to figure out what was wrong. Your HTML code was:

```
<a href="http://www.lsmerch.com/donate" class="donate-button2">DONATE TO LIFESTYLE</a>
```

As you can see there is an "a" tag, but no "button" tag. This would be the proper HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.lsmerch.com/donate">
 <button class="donate-button2">DONATE TO LIFESTYLE</button>
</a>
```

By changing the HTML in inspect element you can see it. This is a problem present in both the header/navigation and the sidebar in your website. I would also work on making the website more responsive to screen size, as I encountered problems when using the inspect element, and you should add the "background-size: cover;" attribute to your banner images, as this will make your images look much better in higher resolutions.

Comment: awesome! that fixes the problem in the header where it wasn't changing color on hover. would you happen to know how to fix the problem in other pages where the corners are not rounding?

Comment: i guess the best question would be what should the html be? because i have been using a tool called Visual Composer, so i havent even a clue what the html is. but i could use my own html if i knew what it should be. any ideas?

Comment: well export your site and upload it somewhere and send it to me to look at.

Comment: export the whole site? not sure how to do that or upload it somewhere else. I can say this though. i researched it a little bit and saw people saying to do this <button type="button">Click Me!</button>

Comment: export the whole site? not sure how to do that. I tried this <button type="donate-button">DONATE</button> but still having trouble. For some reason the text wont center, and I can't seem to be able to change the font or size. For a real life example, you can see the buttons in our header here http://www.lsmerch.com/the-greater-than-we-can-imagine-power-of-reading-the-bible/ and then the same buttons in the sidebar as you scroll down. except the sidebar buttons text is not vertically centered and seems to either be a different font or line height or something.

Comment: Here is another example from our main page. http://www.lsmerch.com/ Here the buttons have the same font and size as the ones in the header but the corners are not rounded.

Comment: I found out what you were doing wrong, you were styling an "a" link as a button. I will edit my answer to show you how it should be.

Comment: Unfortunately the problems you are having is caused by the visual editor within WordPress, and there probably isn't too much you can do. A good thing about you having purchased this theme from themeforest is that through the envato market you can go directly to the creator of the theme for help and support. That is where I would go from there. Best of luck.

Comment: Awesome, so helpful. Thank you so much. I'll make those changes. And thank you for your suggestions as well. You have been so helpful! God bless.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.donate-button {
  display: block;
  height: 45px;
  width: 120px;
  background: rgba(255, 204, 5, .9);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) !important;
  text-align: center;
  font: regular 8px/45px"Montserrat", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
a.donate-button {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.donate-button:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 213, 6, .9) !important;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) !important;
}
```

```html
<a class="donate-button">Done</a>
<button class="donate-button">Button</button>
```

Comment: I think that that is what he has currently, but I don't think that is what he wanted...